# RhoStudio Doesn't Build In XCode - Curl

Tags: iphone, curl, xcode5, rhomobile

Me and my friend are creating an app on RhoStudio and we would like it to work on Apple devices.
It works perfectly on Android, IOS Simulator but isn't compiling correctly to be able to run it on my iPhone via XCode.
When I do make an XCode project with it the project ($ rake build:iphone:setup_xcode_project) there are 3 errors and since im not that advanced at XCode do not understand the errors.
The errors are related with Curl.

[image]


I'll be really appreciated if we could get some help.


**Details**
- Motorola RhoStudio: 4.0.0
- MacBook Pro 2011, v10.9
- XCode v5.0.2

Answer (score 1):

The `strlcat` method changed definition in iOS 7 and Mavericks. It is already defined in the system headers and this definition conflicts with the one in the cURL source.

By looking at the system header, I think you could solve this in a number of ways

- Change target SDK to 6.1, or something earlier than 7.0. This is a quick fix, but might not be what you want.
- Remove the definition in the cURL source (there seems to be no way to #define away it so you need to edit the source).
- `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE =0` should disable all Apple's definitions (did not try this though).

Comment: Thank you @Krumelur, I changed target to 6.0 and all errors have disappeared and does run on my phone. Except that when it opens I get s Server Error saying "Uninitalized constant Rho::Application Trace.."